# Script to access same path on different devices

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to make a batch file that access same place on a different workstation?

Example path: `\\station1\c$\windows\system32\spool\printers`

When running the script I want to be prompted which station I want to access and substitute `station1` with another station name eg. `station2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set /p PcName=Please enter PC Name: || set PcName=station1
set DirPath=\\%PcName%\c$\windows\system32\spool\printers
echo Resulting path: %DirPath%
```

More info: [SET: Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables.](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)